# Analyst Action Data

Tags: historical-data

I want to build models based on **analyst action data that include historical price target changes** from analysts. Yahoo finance only shows the rating change but no price target change for every action. For target price, hey only show the min, max and avg. The data from yahoo finance is also not comprehensive that many of the analysts' rating were missing.

Anyone knows better source (free will be the best) that include the info that is missing from yahoo finance?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that you can achieve this with free sources alone. The standard database for analyst estimates is [I/B/E/S Estimates](https://financial.thomsonreuters.com/en/products/data-analytics/company-data/ibes-estimates.html), which has extremely detailed analyst estimates for "22,000 companies in 100 countries." They've also been doing this for a very long time – If I remember correctly, US estimates go back to the late 1970s. An alternative is Zacks, which also compiles bottoms-up consensus estimates (although the depth of the data is unclear).